# XAML page is not garbage collected in WinRT app on Windows 10 Mobile but works as expected on WP8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp, winrt-xaml

I have a WinRT app built for Windows Phone 8.1. The app has a main page that leads to a page with a list of items and when an item is tapped it leads to a details page for that item. It turns out that when the user clicks on an item and then presses back the first instance of the list page is not garbage collected on Windows 10 Mobile. On Windows Phone 8.1 everything works as expected. The profiling tools show the following paths to root in the memory snapshot.

[image]

RacePage is the list page and there are nine instances because in that particular snapshot I went back and forth 9 times. The Navigation Helper is the standard class from the app template Visual Studio creates. Again I don't think the problem is in my code because the leak does not happen on WP8.1 I have no idea why the items that have events hooked to them are not GCed (it says RefCount handle may that be the issue?). Interestingly the page with the details seems to be GCed properly. The view models are recreated on each navigation (i.e. they are not static)

I would appreciate any help on what is causing the issue and how I can work around it.

Here is the complete code for the page

```
<Page
    x:Class="Medusa.WinRT.RacePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Medusa.WinRT"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="ImageLabelStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,0,0"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource TextStyleMediumFontSize}" />
                <Setter Property="TextLineBounds" Value="Full" />
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap" />
                <Setter Property="LineHeight" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneMidBrush}" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Hub x:Name="pMain" Header="{Binding Title}">
            <Hub.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding BackgroundImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill"  Opacity="0.3"></ImageBrush>
            </Hub.Background>

            <HubSection Header="UNITS" HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderTemplate}">
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Units}" Background="Transparent">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel x:Name="spUnit" Tapped="spUnit_Tapped" Background="Transparent" Tag="{Binding}">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                                        <Image Width="80" Height="72" Source="{Binding MenuImagePath}" ImageFailed="ImageFailed"></Image>
                                        <Grid Width="270" Tag="{Binding}">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition />
                                                <RowDefinition />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Text="{Binding Name}"  Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"/>
                                            <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Width="20" Height="20" Source="Assets/icon-mineral.png"></Image>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MineralCost}" Style="{ThemeResource ImageLabelStyle}"/>
                                            <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="20" Source="{Binding Path=RaceGasIconPath}"></Image>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding GasCost}" Style="{ThemeResource ImageLabelStyle}"/>
                                            <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Width="20" Height="20" Source="{Binding Path=RaceBuildTimeIcon}"></Image>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding BuildTime}" Style="{ThemeResource ImageLabelStyle}"/>
                                            <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" Width="20" Height="20" Source="{Binding Path=RaceSupplyIcon}"></Image>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7" Text="{Binding SupplyCost}" Style="{ThemeResource ImageLabelStyle}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection>

            <HubSection Header="BUILDINGS" HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderTemplate}">
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Buildings}" Background="Transparent">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel x:Name="spBuilding" Tapped="spBuilding_Tapped" Tag="{Binding}" Background="Transparent">
                                    <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17" >
                                        <Image Width="80" Height="72" Source="{Binding MenuImagePath}" ImageFailed="ImageFailed"></Image>
                                        <Grid Width="270">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition />
                                                <RowDefinition />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"/>
                                            <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20" Source="Assets/icon-mineral.png"></Image>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MineralCost}" Style="{ThemeResource ImageLabelStyle}"/>
                                            <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="20" Source="{Binding Path=RaceGasIconPath}"></Image>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding GasCost}" Style="{ThemeResource ImageLabelStyle}"/>
                                            <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Width="20" Height="20" Source="{Binding Path=RaceBuildTimeIcon}"></Image>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding BuildTime}" Style="{ThemeResource ImageLabelStyle}"/>
                                            <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" Width="20" Height="20" Source="{Binding Path=RaceSupplyIcon}"></Image>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7" Text="{Binding SupplyValue}" Style="{ThemeResource ImageLabelStyle}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection>

        </Hub>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Code behind:

```
public sealed partial class RacePage : Page
{
    private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;

    public RacePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        navigationHelper.LoadState += OnNavigationHelperLoadState;
        this.Unloaded += RacePage_Unloaded;
    }

    private void RacePage_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = null;
        navigationHelper.LoadState -= OnNavigationHelperLoadState;
        navigationHelper = null;
    }

    private void OnNavigationHelperLoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        Initialize((Races)e.NavigationParameter);
    }

    private void Initialize(Races race)
    {
        if (DataContext == null)
        {
            var viewModel = new RaceViewModel(App.Settings.CurrentGameInfo, race);
            DataContext = viewModel;
        }
    }

    private void ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Image)sender).Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/noimage80x72.png", UriKind.Absolute));
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }

    private void spUnit_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var unitViewModel = (UnitViewModel)((Panel)sender).Tag;
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(UnitPage), unitViewModel);
    }

    private void spBuilding_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var buildingViewModel = (BuildingViewModel)((Panel)sender).Tag;
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BuildingPage), buildingViewModel);
    }
}
```

### Debugging Story (How I got to this point)

I published an app built with WinRT for WP8.1 and Win10 Mobile. When it got into the market I did some more testing and found out that on W10M the images on the list page start lagging (appear a second later) after about 10 times of back and forth to the details page. While I did test the app on W10M I did not click that much for the issue to become visible and while developing I was testing with the WP8.1 emulator with small amount of memory so I hadn't hit t he issue. The issue does not exist on WP8.1. The issue is reproducible in the emulators.

I assumed some kind of leak and ran the profiling tools. I first noticed that the number of PropertyChanged delegates is increasing. I thought that maybe my ViewModel is holding the reference through an event handler. Since I did not need the two-way databinding I removed the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation but the issue was still there and the delegates were replaced by something called CustomPropertyImpl (it seems like this is infrastructure used for databinding to POCOs).

I then looked at my viewmodels to check if they were static. They were not. I hooked an unloaded handler to the list page and manually set the DataContext to null. This reduced the objects leaked by a very large number and the issue did not reproduce visually but when I looked in the profiling tools the list page was still leaking. It seems like the issue would still happen but you would need hundreds of page loads instead of 10.

Looking at the paths to roots it seems that W10M keeps some objects that have events hooked to them alive. The page has a hub control and two lists of items. The code behind has a couple of event handlers.

The app is published in the Windows Store here - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/sc2-master/9n2cjmrsnd8l

Edit: as requested the NavigationHelper class (with the non-Windows Phone part removed)

```
    [Windows.Foundation.Metadata.WebHostHidden]
    public class NavigationHelper : DependencyObject
    {
        private Page Page { get; set; }
        private Frame Frame { get { return this.Page.Frame; } }

        public NavigationHelper(Page page)
        {
            this.Page = page;
            this.Page.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
            {
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
                Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
#endif
            };

            // Undo the same changes when the page is no longer visible
            this.Page.Unloaded += (sender, e) =>
            {
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
                Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
#endif
            };
        }

        #region Navigation support

        RelayCommand _goBackCommand;
        RelayCommand _goForwardCommand;

        public RelayCommand GoBackCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_goBackCommand == null)
                {
                    _goBackCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        () => this.GoBack(),
                        () => this.CanGoBack());
                }
                return _goBackCommand;
            }
            set
            {
                _goBackCommand = value;
            }
        }

        public RelayCommand GoForwardCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_goForwardCommand == null)
                {
                    _goForwardCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        () => this.GoForward(),
                        () => this.CanGoForward());
                }
                return _goForwardCommand;
            }
        }

        public virtual bool CanGoBack()
        {
            return this.Frame != null && this.Frame.CanGoBack;
        }

        public virtual bool CanGoForward()
        {
            return this.Frame != null && this.Frame.CanGoForward;
        }


        public virtual void GoBack()
        {
            if (this.Frame != null && this.Frame.CanGoBack) this.Frame.GoBack();
        }

        public virtual void GoForward()
        {
            if (this.Frame != null && this.Frame.CanGoForward) this.Frame.GoForward();
        }

#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
        private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.GoBackCommand.CanExecute(null))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                this.GoBackCommand.Execute(null);
            }
        }
#endif

        #endregion

        #region Process lifetime management

        private String _pageKey;

        public event LoadStateEventHandler LoadState;
        public event SaveStateEventHandler SaveState;

        public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            var frameState = SuspensionManager.SessionStateForFrame(this.Frame);
            this._pageKey = "Page-" + this.Frame.BackStackDepth;

            if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New)
            {
                // Clear existing state for forward navigation when adding a new page to the
                // navigation stack
                var nextPageKey = this._pageKey;
                int nextPageIndex = this.Frame.BackStackDepth;
                while (frameState.Remove(nextPageKey))
                {
                    nextPageIndex++;
                    nextPageKey = "Page-" + nextPageIndex;
                }

                // Pass the navigation parameter to the new page
                if (this.LoadState != null)
                {
                    this.LoadState(this, new LoadStateEventArgs(e.Parameter, null));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Pass the navigation parameter and preserved page state to the page, using
                // the same strategy for loading suspended state and recreating pages discarded
                // from cache
                if (this.LoadState != null)
                {
                    this.LoadState(this, new LoadStateEventArgs(e.Parameter, (Dictionary<String, Object>)frameState[this._pageKey]));
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            var frameState = SuspensionManager.SessionStateForFrame(this.Frame);
            var pageState = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
            if (this.SaveState != null)
            {
                this.SaveState(this, new SaveStateEventArgs(pageState));
            }
            frameState[_pageKey] = pageState;
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public delegate void LoadStateEventHandler(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e);
    public delegate void SaveStateEventHandler(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e);

    public class LoadStateEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public Object NavigationParameter { get; private set; }
        public Dictionary<string, Object> PageState { get; private set; }

        public LoadStateEventArgs(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<string, Object> pageState)
            : base()
        {
            this.NavigationParameter = navigationParameter;
            this.PageState = pageState;
        }
    }

    public class SaveStateEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Object> PageState { get; private set; }

        public SaveStateEventArgs(Dictionary<string, Object> pageState)
            : base()
        {
            this.PageState = pageState;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Added it. I have removed the inactive #ifdefs that only apply to Windows and not to WP and the excessive comments

Comment: Such issues are quite hard to debug. Maybe first try to remove NavigationHelper completely (since it just loads and saves state) and do forced GC.Collect in page unload, just to check out if those two things has any effect on the issue.

Comment: I was playing with Forced GC. The performance tools have a button to force GC. Couldn't find any point where forcing GC made a difference. I will continue to test different things. For now the problem is contained enough that it is not a problem for the users and I will try to fight it when I have time (it is a side project after all). Maybe first thing will be to build a separate app to reproduce the problem in a minimal settings.

Comment: And what about removing NavigationHelper, does not make any difference?

Comment: Haven't tried yet but the back button handlers are there. I will have to move them to each of the pages.

Comment: Since you cannot debug using WinDBG on phone devices, you could still save a dump file using VS, then open it up in WinDBG, load up SOS extension and use "!GCRoot" command to figure out what keeps those objects native. Relevant link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kristoffer/2007/01/09/debugging-memory-usage-in-managed-code-using-windbg/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your view model is static or lives on some sort of container (so won't get garbage collected after created), this  looks to me to be related to a long-time known issue (which I believe it has not been fixed yet) related to the `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` event that does not get detached automatically when the page is unloaded!

I'd recommend trying to raise `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` for each of the commands **after** the page has fully unloaded and gc'ed.

Comment: The model is not static and I don't think it lives in any container. I also tend to skip commands and expose methods on the view model then hook events in the code behind and manually call the VM methods. You can see the instantiation of the view model in the page code behind. I don't keep any reference to it other than the DataContext of the page.